# ReportViewer Missing URL Parameter : IteretionId

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, reportviewer

I working with MSCRM I make report (.rdl) and deploy on CRM and when I run report on CRM It's run correctly.

then I make some webpage for run CRM report I made before in remote processing mode. report viewer not display report.

then I open Event Log to see what happen I got this warning message

> Missing URL Parameter : IterationId

I try to research and fix by using this code in my webpage

```
var pathQuery = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToLower();

        var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();

        if (pathQuery.StartsWith("reserved.reportviewerwebcontrol.axd") && !url.Contains("iterationid"))
        {
            var resourceStreamId = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ResourceStreamId"];

            if (resourceStreamId == null) { return; }

            if (resourceStreamId.ToString().Equals("Blank.gif", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Context.RewritePath(String.Concat(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, "&IterationId=0"));
            }
        }
```

But, Report still not show in my web

anyone can help

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.

I found solution for my problem from [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b44a0452-d71a-4e69-b7e0-af74b9f6bde7/missing-url-parameter-iterationid?forum=sqlreportingservices)

I delete all "Line Control" in my Report and it's work!